# Create object type from union of keys

Tags: typescript

I know about the `keyof` operator and how to create a union type consisting of keys of that object like this:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

type Goo = keyof Foo; // "a" | "b"
```

I would like to do the exact opposite and create a new object type from the union of keys.

```
const MakeTuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;
const Types = MakeTuple("A", "B", "C");
type TypeVariant = typeof Types[number];

type VariantObject = {
  // This gives error consider using a mapped object but I'm not sure how to do that
  [type: TypeVariant]: [boolean, boolean, boolean, string[]];
}
```

So what I want is to take a union of keys and generate a type that contains an value for each key of type `[boolean, boolean, boolean, string[]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the predefined `Record` mapped type

```
const MakeTuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;
const Types = MakeTuple("A", "B", "C");
type TypeVariant = typeof Types[number];

type VariantObject = Record< TypeVariant, [boolean, boolean, boolean, string[]] >
```