# How to create a typescript object definition from an array of keys

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function in TypeScript which essentially takes an array of strings and converts them into an object with each element of the array becoming a property.

I'm struggling the type definition right though...

```
const func = (keys: Array<string>) => {
    return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: true,
      };
    }, {});
  };

  const result = func(["foo"]); // Type = {}, what I want is, Type = { "foo": true }
```

Comment: Well, this seems to work already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create object type from union of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663811/create-object-type-from-union-of-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work

```
function func<Key extends string>(keys: Key[]) {
    return keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: true,
    }), {} as Record<Key, boolean>);
}

const result = func(["foo", "bar"]);
```

Comment: According to the VSCode code completion `result` still has the type `Record<string, boolean>` instead of `{foo: boolean, bar: boolean}`...

Comment: for me it's `const result: Record<"foo" | "bar", boolean>`.
what TS version u have?
(this: `{foo: boolean, bar: boolean}` does not look generic)

Comment: Oh I just noticed that it works when I pass in the array directly like `const result = func(["foo", "bar"]);` but not when I store it another variable `const arr = ["foo", "bar"]; const result = func(arr);`... I'm using TypeScript 5.0.4.

Comment: you can use `const arr = ["foo", "bar"] as const` for more accurate types. by default it will be `string[]`. (or use values of an `enum`)